# How to do find_all() in Beautifulsoup only by name of attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to get a `href` from `Wikipedia`, but I'm only interested the one that is inside of `td data-sort-value`
for example:

```
<td data-sort-value="34">
     <a href="/wiki/Provinces_of_Afghanistan" title="Provinces of Afghanistan">34 provinces</a> 
</td>
```

From this, I would need to get `/wiki/Provinces_of_Afghanistan`.
My problem is that I need to get this from a list of countries, and the number in `td data-sort-value` depends on the country.

My question is, is it possible to write a generic value so I can take all the `td data-sort-value`?
This is my code, and I tried just writing `row.find_all("td", {"data-sort-value"})` instead of `row.find_all("td", {"data-sort-value":"34"})`, but it doesn't work.
(If I write a number it works but just with that number).

Thank you!

```
def parseAdminRegions():
    
    name_Regions = page_soup.find_all()

    counter = 0
    for row in page_soup.find_all("tr", {"valign":"top"}):
        for box in row.find_all("td", {"data-sort-value":"34"}):
            counter = 0
            for region in box.find_all("a", href=True):
                counter = counter + 1
                part_link = region["href"]
                 
                full_link = editable_url + region["href"]
                print(full_link)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it this way**

```
find_all('td', attrs={'data-sort-value' : True}
```

**Example**

```
import bs4

content ='''
<td data-sort-value="34">
     <a href="/wiki/Provinces_of_Afghanistan" title="Provinces of Afghanistan">34 provinces</a> 
</td>
<td data-sort-value="45">
     <a href="/wiki/Provinces_of_ABC" title="Provinces of Afghanistan">45 provinces</a> 
</td>
<td data-sort-value="48">
     <a href="/wiki/Provinces_of_XYZ" title="Provinces of Afghanistan">48 provinces</a> 
</td>

'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content)

[item.find('a')['href'] for item in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'data-sort-value' : True})]
```

**Output**

```
['/wiki/Provinces_of_Afghanistan',
 '/wiki/Provinces_of_ABC',
 '/wiki/Provinces_of_XYZ']
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''
<td data-sort-value="34">
     <a href="/wiki/Provinces_of_Afghanistan" title="Provinces of Afghanistan">34 provinces</a> 
</td>
<td>
     <a href="/wiki/ab" title="Provinces of Afghanistan">34 provinces</a> 
</td>
'''

link_list = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('td', attrs = {'data-sort-value' : True}):
    link_list.append(item.find('a')['href'])
print(link_list)
```